# Erroneously prompted for username and password when using aws-heptio-authenticator for EKS on Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have an [EKS cluster](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) set up.

My setup:

- kubeconfig file
- AWS IAM credentials saved as `[default]` in    `~/.aws/credentials`
- a user binding on the cluster which provides the user with
  system:master

When I use [aws-heptio-authenticator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html) to authenticate to the cluster with an IAM user via my Mac (High Sierra), it works as expected.  I am able to authenticate against the cluster automatically when using kubectl commands.

When I use the same kubeconfig file and same user from a Windows laptop, with the AWS credentials stored in ~/.aws/credentials as the default, I am prompted for a username, and then a password.  Neither of these seem to be used, and the prompted is repeated over an over again.

Has anyone run into this, or resolved this issue?

Comment: HAve you tried downloading kubectl for aws? it is slightly different for windows and might help you: https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.10.3/2018-06-05/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe

Comment: I'll try that and report back, thanks.  We did find that installing/using the Linux Subsystem for Windows 10 allowed us to authenticate as expected

Comment: @Mr.Budris did you find a solution? I'm experiencing the same issue on Linux